# The MDX function failed because current coordinate is empty

Tags: ssas

After updating the cube I'm getting this message in EXCEL for some users, it started a week, before it run normally, and had no new deploy of CUBE. I am using the SQL 2014 version with the latest service pack installed. I do not understand the reason for this error what it may be causing because the mdx query are done by the excel interface. If anyone has an idea how I can solve it. You see that this happened in some previous versions of SQL, but that was corrected through "SP", regarding SQL 2014 I did not find anything, and how to solve this.

Any idea what might be causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the solution. Thank you

Solution:
Removed last service pack, returned to normal operation